How to logs are logging in application insights using managed identity in .NET Core?
I need the process of how to logging metrics (logs) in application in sights using managed identity.
Managed identity for application insight using .NET Core.
But already I tried application insights => add role assignment give this role as Monitoring Metrics Publisher permission and mapped managed identity.
Also local authentication is disabled.
When I disabled local authentication, the logs are not logged in application insights. They are logged only enable case only.
services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(config =>
{
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        ManagedIdentityClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    });
    config.SetAzureTokenCredential(credential);
});
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    ConnectionString = "Application insights connection string"
});

I passed application insights in appsetting.json file like this format
"ApplicationInsights": {
  "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "EnableApplicationInsights": true
}


Can you show to code that configures application insights?

services.Configure(config =>
{
var credential=  new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
ManagedIdentityClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});
config.SetAzureTokenCredential(credential);

});
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(
new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
ConnectionString ="Application insights connection string"
});

above code i configured in  .net core

Can you please share more details about the issue?

i disable local authentication through azure portal
go to properties and local authentication option.

i passed application insights in appsetting.json file like this format "ApplicationInsights": {
"ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"EnableApplicationInsights": true
}

@ramuyepuganti - You can edit the details in the posted question itself.

Are you running the App locally or the deployed App Service?

@Harshitha  when i disabled local authentication logs are logged in azure portal.but when local authentication is enabled what happended ?

In that case also still logs are logged?

deployed service only

When I disabled local authentication, the logs are not logged in application insights. but in question i see this vice-versa

but why what is the use of local authenticaton using managed identity?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

using managed identity case when ever local authentication diabled in portal logs are logged correct

Is your local authentication is enabled everytime or you will change it ?

services.Configure(config =>
{
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
ManagedIdentityClientId = "xxxxx",
});
config.SetAzureTokenCredential(credential);
});
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(
new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=xx;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=xxxxx"
});

right now am not assigning any role to application insights and not mapped any managed identity but logs are logged

As you have configured your app with application insights connection string, yes logs will be logged.

Can we connect in chat

using managed identity connection string is manadatory?

Hi Harsitha i need how to write sample code for application insight access using managaed identity with serilog

First make sure your app is connected to managed identity and able to log to application insights.Later that can be configured with serilog.

managed identity is working fine

but MSDoc they are saying using managed identity you need to assign this role(Monitoring Metrics Publisher) and mapped particulr managed identity client Id

Can you please edit the question with your current issue

please come once to chat box

which version of app insights sdk are you using ?

using 2.22.0 version
